# How to get shaded background in xyplot in lattice for different grouping variables in different panels

Tags: r, lattice

By pulling up the `data.frame` that comes with the package `lattice` and `latticeExtra` we get the following :

```
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
data("environmental")
```

This is the way the `head(environmental)` looks:

```
ozone radiation temperature wind
41       190          67  7.4
36       118          72  8.0
12       149          74 12.6
18       313          62 11.5
23       299          65  8.6
19        99          59 13.8
```

Now please consider the code for the plot and the plot itself:

```
temp.cut <- equal.count(environmental$temperature,4)

   xyplot(ozone~radiation | temp.cut,data = environmental,
   panel = function(x,y,...){
   panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
   x <- 1:400
   panel.xblocks(x,x>20&x<50,col = 'green',alpha=0.2)
   panel.xblocks(x,x>80&x<100,col = 'blue',alpha=0.2)
   })
```

[image]

My doubt is how do I get the shaded areas to behave sensibly for each panel ? Say I want blue shade in the first panel but not on the others, same reasoning apply for the green shaded area, on the second panel but not on the others. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I thin you can get some control using `panel.number()` i.e. `panel.xblocks(x[panel.number()==1], x > 20 & x < 50, col = 'green', alpha=0.2)`

Comment: ps not sure if this is THE way to do it but it is A way to avoid the hard -coding of `x` : use `x <- sort(x)` instead